# Android app not compatible with tablets

Tags: android, google-play, tablet

I just developed a new app (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.viewpointus.workstatement), when I uploaded it to Play store it doesn't seam to be compatible with tablets, but it does install in the AVD (Android Virtual Device), also on my Nexus 9 tablet I installed it. specifications:

```
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 21
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"  android:required="false" />
```

Comment: how did you know that your app is not compatible with tablet if you yourself installed it on your own device?

Comment: @SecretCoder I installed it trough Android Studio (Run App, selected my connected tablet device) but on the Play store it's not showing, also in the supported devices list (in developer console) it shows as unsupported.

Comment: i think you done wrong on putting it to play store or in your AndroidManifest. Please post your androidmanifest here

Comment: @SecretCoder [here](https://gist.github.com/ephraim123/1540c3eb7c71ece81239a03d619d26b0) is the manifast file

Answer (score 1):

You will still be able to download it and install it in tables. But the Google Play Store will not mark it as 'optimized for tablets' since you don't have screenshots that show how would your program look like in 7' and 10' tablets in portrait and landscape mode.

Comment: the screenshots are not the issue, this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sp.app.myWorkClock has no screenshots for tablets and was able to download on my tablet, also I did upload a tablet screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

It installs to an emulator properly since it's for testing. I think you can even install it in tablets so long as you have the APK.

But having Google Play mark it as compatible with tablets, you must first pass the [Confirm the App's Platform and Screen Compatibility Ranges](https://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/launch-checklist.html#confirm-platform) with regards to tablets in the [Launch Checklist](https://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/launch-checklist.html).

You can check this [Screens Distribution](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html) docs for more info on screen compatibility distributions. Cheers!

Comment: thanks for your respond, according to google `<supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true" />`

Comment: Your welcome. If your concern seems to be okay, go ahead and accept the answer that helped you the most, to tag your post as already answered. Cheers! :)

Comment: sorry I didn't finish, and got posted by mistake (lol), according to google [screens support](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support) android will try to accommodate to it's layout by its own, it's only a matter of good design practice to even create specific layouts and bitmaps. also according to [screens distribution](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html#FilteringHandsetApps) it seams that by default it will include all devices (with proper API)